# Why I'm getting "NullPointerException" error?

Tags: android

My problem is getPostId() is giving me null value in addNotification(pst.getPublisher(), pst.getPostId()) . here getPostId giving null value but getPublisher() give correct value. but in add

```
isLikes(pst.getPostid(),holder.like);
mrLikes(holder.likes,pst.getPostid());
getComments(pst.getPostid(),holder.comments);
```

getPostid() giving correct value and working fine. In

```
editPost(pst.getPostid());
```

postimage.setOnClickLisener it also getting null value.

```
I tried to call inside the setOnClickListener still didn't work.Specific part is given below.


 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        pst = mpost.get(position);
        //String postid = getRef
        if(mContext==null){
            return;
        }
        Glide.with(mContext).load(pst.getPostimage()).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.praceholder)).into(holder.postimage);
        holder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.description.setText(pst.getDescription());
        holder.catagory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.catagory.setText(pst.getCatagory());
        holder.location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.location.setText(pst.getLocation());
        //}
        publisherinfo(holder.image_profile,holder.uname,holder.publisher,pst.getPublisher());
        isLikes(pst.getPostid(),holder.like);
        mrLikes(holder.likes,pst.getPostid());
        getComments(pst.getPostid(),holder.comments);
holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(holder.like.getTag().equals("like")){
                   // pst = mpost.get(position);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("likes").child(pst.getPostid()).child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                    addNotifications(pst.getPublisher(),pst.getPostid());
                }else{
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("likes").child(pst.getPostid()).child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });

 holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext,view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.edit:
                                editPost(pst.getPostid());
                                return true;
                            case R.id.delete:
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(pst.getPostid()).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                return true;
                            case R.id.report:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext,"reported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
 holder.postimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                //pst = mpost.get(position);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("postid",pst.getPostid());
                editor.apply();
                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new PostDetailsFragment()).commit();

            }
        });
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: I don't see the `addNotification` that you say has the error anywhere, which makes it hard to help. I know Alex asked you to post less code; the best way to do that is to reproduce the problem from scratch with minimal code, rather than removing bits from the question.

Comment: I edited my post. Can you check it now please?